# Using zend_service_amazon, but not seeing any output

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework

I'm playing around with the Amazon developer's API and I'm not getting anything.

Here is my code. I am using `echo` to see if anything is happening and all I am getting is a blank webpage. I expected the array of search results to be echoed.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
require_once('Zend/Service/Amazon.php');

$amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon('AKIAJQBYUXIFWUIX6W6A', 'US', 'YGV9zePfKejV6C3dpaP/NtnhjGLfWQsccdGSSL50');
$results = $amazon->itemSearch(array('SearchIndex' => 'Books',
                                     'Keywords' => 'php'));
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->Title . '<br />';
}

    ?>
```

getting a blank page still

Comment: tried replacing $artistName with 'Kesha' and still no results from echo

Comment: Blank pages are usually the result of an error with output turned off. Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);` in your bootstrap. It's also useful to install xdebug and see the stack trace it provides.

Comment: @cillosis i am using now this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is blank because you are no getting any results:

This is the $results dump using your published code:

```
Amazon object(Zend_Service_Amazon_ResultSet)#103 (4) {
  ["_results":protected] => object(DOMNodeList)#105 (0) {
  }
  ["_dom":protected] => object(DOMDocument)#101 (0) {
  }
  ["_xpath":protected] => object(DOMXPath)#104 (0) {
  }
  ["_currentIndex":protected] => int(0)
}
```

There are several issues to resolve to make this work, the biggest one being this:

> **The following changes will take effect on 11/1/2011:**
>  *Associate Tag Parameter:* Every request made to the API should include
>   a valid Associate Tag. Any request that does not contain a valid
>   Associate Tag will be rejected with an appropriate error message. For
>   details on the Associate Tag parameter, please refer to our Developer
>   guide.

Currently the constructor for `Zend_Service_Amazon` does not include the *Associate Tag* parameter and the `_prepareOptions()` method does not set the option.

I'm sure someone has a fix for this, otherwise it's time to dig in and extend... Good Luck

[Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html)
[Changes to Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/api-changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Zend_Service_Amazon is out of date and uses old WSDL.
see http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-12046

wait for 1.12 or use the provided batch file.