# Output not generated by zend_service_amazon

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

I am using Zend Framework to retrieve book information from amazon. This code is not showing any error in the page neither displaying any results. Can you solve this?

```
define("AMAZON_API_KEY","#################");
define("AMAZON_SECRET_KEY","############################################");
require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon.php';
$amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon(AMAZON_API_KEY, 'US', AMAZON_SECRET_KEY);
$results = $amazon->itemSearch(array('SearchIndex' => 'Books','Keywords' => 'history'));
print_r($results);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->Title . '<br />';
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Prakash

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using zend_service_amazon, but not seeing any output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770971/using-zend-service-amazon-but-not-seeing-any-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fix for the amazon API zend should be updated in next release of framework. If you don't like to wait for that release, you can apply the patch file from here http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12046 to your copy to fix this error. Mine is solved. Hope this works for you too..

If you have problem making the patch, let me know

Comment: Nice find on the patch, I was looking for a solution to help you too; I didn't realize yesterday that the Zend Framework Amazon Service was so broken.  I applied the patch, and changed the search parameters from your question to this: `$search  = array('SearchIndex'  => 'Books',
                     'Keywords'     => 'history',
                     'AssociateTag' => 'yourtag-20');` and it seems to work now.